# Kafka server does not start

Tags: apache-kafka, homebrew, apache-zookeeper

I installed Kafka and Zookeeper on my OSX machine using Homebrew, and I'm trying to launch Zookeeper and Kafka-server following [this](https://medium.com/@Ankitthakur/apache-kafka-installation-on-mac-using-homebrew-a367cdefd273) blog post.

`zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties` works fine, as confirmed using `telnet localhost 2181`. Launching `kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties` results in the following output (error at the end). What should I do to launch the Kafka server effectively?

```
$ kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
[2018-11-16 13:58:53,513] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,002] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,003] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,024] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,034] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,034] INFO Client environment:host.name=martinas-mbp.fritz.box (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,034] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_192 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,035] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,035] INFO Client environment:java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,035] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.27.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.0.0-sources.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.0.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/michelangelo/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/s_/_q9gnhkn0816xyzxh3sd7vdh0000gp/T/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:os.arch=x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:os.version=10.12.6 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:user.name=michelangelo (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:user.home=/Users/michelangelo (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,036] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/bin (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,038] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@6ef888f6 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,055] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,055] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,069] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,078] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x10000041838000b, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,082] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,277] INFO Cluster ID = 8TON7fHXTUuVjzYM9iHZHQ (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,352] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    advertised.host.name = null
    advertised.listeners = null
    advertised.port = null
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name = 
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.id = 0
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    host.name = 
    inter.broker.listener.name = null
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.0-IV1
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = null
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 2.0-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 168
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1000012
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    port = 9092
    principal.builder.class = null
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,361] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    advertised.host.name = null
    advertised.listeners = null
    advertised.port = null
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name = 
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.id = 0
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    host.name = 
    inter.broker.listener.name = null
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.0-IV1
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = null
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 2.0-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 168
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1000012
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    port = 9092
    principal.builder.class = null
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,384] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,384] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,385] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,411] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs. A Kafka instance in another process or thread is using this directory.
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$lockLogDirs$1(LogManager.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.lockLogDirs(LogManager.scala:236)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:97)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:968)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:237)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,413] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,417] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,420] INFO Session: 0x10000041838000b closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,421] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000041838000b (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,422] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-11-16 13:58:54,423] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:55,390] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:55,390] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:55,390] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:56,393] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:56,393] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:56,393] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:57,398] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:57,398] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2018-11-16 13:58:57,407] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-11-16 13:58:57,408] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2018-11-16 13:58:57,411] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Can you share more of the output log? These lines don't contain the reason for the shutdown.

Comment: I edited the question to include the entire output log.

Comment: By the way, a solution I found is to follow the Homebrew services manager (see [here](https://gist.github.com/jarrad/3528a5d9128fe693ca84#gistcomment-2304762)) and use the commands `brew services start kafka` and similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs. A Kafka instance in another process or thread is using this directory.
```

There's another instance of kafka running. Kill it first.

You should be able to identify it with

```
lsof /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs/.lock
```

EDIT:

try `brew services stop kafka` first.

Comment: Thanks! Are there reasons to prefer NOT using the Homebrew command?

Comment: @albus Not really, other than it's specific to Mac and you need to relearn how to start Kafka if using Linux. The brew command is just a wrapper around the other command.

Comment: this approach really worked for me, in addition to this don't forget to delete the logs directory before restarting the kafka and zookeeper servers. thanks alot @edson-medina